# String formatting with Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to build a MySQL query and to do that, I have a loop for string formatting. Anyways, I've simplified it in the following code.

```
staticthing = "http://www.forbes.com/pictures/mkm45gmllk/f-p-journe-chronomètre-souverain-platinum/"
#do not edit above this line

sql = u"insert blah blah blah"
for x in range(10):
    sql += u"('%s')" % staticthing.decode('utf-8') #insert into string
```

How can I insert the `staticthing` variable into my `sql` variable? Right now, it changes the `è` to `?`

Thanks so much. I've been working on this for so long and figured I'd give in and post on here. Unicode is always messing with my head.

Comment: Where are you seeing `è` as `?`? Is it your python terminal or mysql admin interface or web page or what else?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This was in PyScripter.

Comment: Add `#coding=utf-8` at the top of your program and let me know if it helps in proper expression of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [string.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead:

```
sql += u"('{0}')".format(staticthing.decode('utf-8'))
```